# BleachBit and other programs report No module named 'gtk' ModuleNotFoundError:

Tags: python, import, gtk

I am new to Ubuntu 18.04 and an aspiring and learning Python self-taught student I expect I did something something unsmart when installing Python 3.7.1 on Ubuntu 18.04. I did have Bleachbit working but now when attempt to open BLeachBit and a couple of other programs with sudo I get the same response:

```
      $ sudo bleachbit
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/bleachbit", line 38, in <module>
      import gtk
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gtk'
```

I used the following command and the system reports that two versions of GTK are installed:

```
    $ dpkg -l libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0
    Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
```

|       Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig- 
        aWait/Trig-pend
        |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
        ||/ Name                       Version            Architecture
        Description
        +++-============================
        ii  libgtk-3-0:amd64           3.22.30-1ubuntu1   amd64
        GTK+ graphical user interface library
        ii  libgtk2.0-0:amd64          2.24.32-1ubuntu1   amd64
        GTK+ graphical user interface library

I believe the GTK is installed.

How to I get the GTK to import to where it is needed.
I have configured the virtualwrapper 'workon" working and have configured Python so I can choose between Python 3.6.6  and Python 3.71 via

```
    sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

I am not sure if that would have misconfigured Python some how.

I would appreciate some direction as to next steps or just wipe disk and re-install Ubuntu.....

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

The packages you found using `dpkg` refer to C system libraries.

You need the Python library that binds to these libraries; it is called `PyGTK`, and is listed [on this BleachBit project page](https://www.bleachbit.org/documentation/installation).

You can use `pip` to install it: `pip install PyGTK`